# I don't seem to get DataStoreService working on Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox, roblox-studio

I cannot get to save data in a roblox game.

```
local players = game:GetService("Players") 
local dss = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local gameData = dss:GetDataStore("Nara")
players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player) 


    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder") 
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats" 
    leaderstats.Parent = player 


    local coins = Instance.new("IntValue")
    coins.Name = "Coins"
    coins.Parent = leaderstats

    local success, result = pcall(function()
        local r = gameData:GetAsync(player.UserId)["Coins"]
        
        return r
    end)

    if success then
        print("success: " .. result)
        coins.Value = result
    else
        print(result)
    end




end)

players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    print("player removed")
    local key = player.UserId
    
    local data = {
        ["Coins"] = player:WaitForChild("leaderstats").Coins.Value
    }
    
    local success, err = pcall(function()
        gameData:SetAsync(key, data)
    end)

    if success then
        print("Data saved successfully")
    else
        print("Failed to save data with error: ", err)
    end
    
end)



game.ReplicatedStorage.Buy.OnServerInvoke = function(player, item)
    if not player:FindFirstChild(item) then
        if player.leaderstats.Coins.Value >= game.ReplicatedStorage.Items:WaitForChild(item).cost.Value then
            player.leaderstats.Coins.Value = player.leaderstats.Coins.Value - game.ReplicatedStorage.Items:WaitForChild(item).cost.Value
            local owned = Instance.new("BoolValue")
            owned.Name = item
            owned.Parent = player
            player.Backpack:ClearAllChildren()
            game.ReplicatedStorage.Items:WaitForChild(item):Clone().Parent = player.Backpack
            return item
        else
            return "not enough coins"
        end
    else
        player.Backpack:ClearAllChildren()
        game.ReplicatedStorage.Items:WaitForChild(item):Clone().Parent = player.Backpack
        return "owned " .. item
    end
end
```

i tried more ways i dont know whats wrong.

I was expecting for the Coins IntValue to be saved then loaded when player joins. I tried everything but didnt get it to work. The value is created and nothing destroyed it. The code gets stuck at pcall for saving, tried to see where using `print`. Thanks